# How can I overload [] operator in C++ for a function of two args?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a class Priority Queue with method push() which takes two args: value and priority.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class PriorityQueue
{
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> _queue;

public:
    int top();
    int pop();
    void push(int, int);
    int size();
    PriorityQueue();
    PriorityQueue(int, int);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, PriorityQueue&);
};
```

How can I overload [] operator for it to work like this:

```
queue[priority]=value;
```

should mean

```
queue.push(priority, value);
```

?

Comment: Have `operator[] ` return a new object that in turn overrides `operator=` to actually calls `push`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: The missing part here is what do you expect `value = queue[priority];` to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return type which will do the `push` on `operator=`, something like:

```
class PriorityQueue
{
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> _queue;

    struct Proxy
    {
        PriorityQueue* queue;
        int priority;

        Proxy& operator=(int value) { queue->push(priority, value); return *this; }
    };

public:
    // ...
    Proxy operator[](int priority) { return {this, priority}; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I overload [] operator in C++ for a function of two args?

The subscript operator is always a binary operator i.e. it always has two operands. If you define the subscript as a member operator, then the left hand operand will be `*this` and as such you can only have one more operand.

> How can I overload [] operator for it to work like this:
>
> ```
> queue[priority]=value;
> ```

In the subscript operator overload, return an object that points to `*this` and has an overloaded assignment operator that calls `queue.push(priority, value)`.